# Property assignment expected.javascript and Expression expected.javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I encountered the VSCode error "Expression expected. ts(1009)" while opening one of the js and HTML files.

```
<script>
    var tokens = [ {% for item in tabledata %} "{{item.name}}",  {% endfor %} ]
    var quantity = [ {% for item in tabledata %} {{item.quantity}},  {% endfor %} ]
</script>
```

//the above code is not working why. It's part of the HTML script tag. I want to link my pie chart with my table data but it's not working.

```
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);
let test = []
// Add data
for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    test.push({
        Token: tokens[i],
        Units: quantity[i]
    });
} 
chart.data = test ;

// Add and configure Series
var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "Token";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "Units";
pieSeries.labels.template.disabled = true;

chart.radius = am4core.percent(95);
// Create custom legend
chart.events.on("ready", function (event) {
    // populate our custom legend when chart renders
    chart.customLegend = document.getElementById('legend');
    pieSeries.dataItems.each(function (row, i) {
        var color = chart.colors.getIndex(i);
        var percent = Math.round(row.values.value.percent * 100) / 100;
        var value = row.value;
        legend.innerHTML += '<div class="legend-item" id="legend-item-' + i + '" onclick="toggleSlice(' + i + ');" onmouseover="hoverSlice(' + i + ');" onmouseout="blurSlice(' + i + ');" style="color: ' + color + ';"><div class="legend-marker" style="background: ' + color + '"></div>' + row.category + '<div class="legend-value">' + value + ' | ' + percent + '%</div></div>';
    });
});

function toggleSlice(item) {
    var slice = pieSeries.dataItems.getIndex(item);
    if (slice.visible) {
        slice.hide();
    } else {
        slice.show();
    }
}

function hoverSlice(item) {
    var slice = pieSeries.slices.getIndex(item);
    slice.isHover = true;
}

function blurSlice(item) {
    var slice = pieSeries.slices.getIndex(item);
    slice.isHover = false;
}
```

[this the error it's showing why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CQBj.jpg)
please check this image.

Comment: Because it's expecting an expression, and it's getting `%`. Are you using some kind of framework that uses `{% ... %}`?